# Boolean to Visibility Converter in Win RT XAML not working first time

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Strange one when working in XAML for Windows RT (windows store app) today, when `IsValid=true` is set from my view model  my boolean to visibility converter does not work the first time (my path remains hidden), but then does display correctly visibility subsequent times after that.

Is this a bug, or what could be going on?

I want to show my tick on `IsValid=true` including initial time:

```
<Path x:Name="MyTick" Data="F1 M 45.12,5.49L 21.255,40.8L 20.4525,40.8L 0,23.2875L 5.775,15.7875L 19.2525,27.3L 37.695,-1.90735e-006L 45.12,5.49 Z " 
Fill="#FF008500" Grid.Column="1" Width="42" Height="42" Margin="24,12,12,0" 
Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Visibility="{Binding IsValid, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

resorting to setting the visibility on code behind of the .xaml.cs does work, but this defeats the purpose of MVVM for such a simple operation and I'd prefer not to do it this way.

This problem also occurs on first time of a textblock I need to show/hide on `IsValid=true` also. First time, it still is collapsed, second time I raise the property changed, it works fine. :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... It was my own stupid fault, it seems I had another condition in the getter of the `IsValid` property which was always `false` when it shouldn't have been.

Fixed :)