# Hide the group header of a listview by binding in Windows Store App

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to remove group headers for groups where the header title is empty. But I can not make the binding in HeaderContainerStyle work. Neither can I set visibility on the TextBlock in TemplateHeader 'cause that will leave a small space and not be completely invisible.

This is my XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource 
        x:Name="MenuItemsGrouped" 
        IsSourceGrouped="True"
        Source="{Binding MenuItems}" />
</Page.Resources>

<ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MenuItemsGrouped}}"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding GroupHeaderVisibility}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Does anyone have a solution - and maybe a reason the binding won't work?

EDIT:

Ok, it's is actually a limitation in Windows Store Apps and earlier Silverlight apps:

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Microsoft Silverlight
> supported the ability to use a Binding expression to supply the Value
> for a Setter in a Style. The Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding
> usage for Setter.Value (the Binding won't evaluate and the Setter has
> no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result
> either). When you convert XAML styles from WPF or Silverlight XAML,
> replace any Binding expression usages with strings or objects that set
> values, or refactor the values as shared StaticResource values rather
> than Binding-obtained values.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.setter

And see also [Silverlight: How to use a binding in setter for a style (or an equivalent work around)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878189/silverlight-how-to-use-a-binding-in-setter-for-a-style-or-an-equivalent-work-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to bind the Visibility of the root element of HeaderTemplate.

```
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Visibility = "{Binding GroupHeaderVisibility}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

It should work.Good luck!

[Edit]

I have figured out a solution, it's not very elegant, but it works. Here are the steps:

1. Add this xaml code to your ListView:

   ```
       <ListView.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <VirtualizingStackPanel />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
   ```

2.Get a copy of ContainerStyle of GroupStyle(Right click the Listview on the design surface.Select: "Edit GroupStyle"->"ContainerStyle"). Then remove this line from the attributes of ContentControl:

```
Margin = "4"
```

3.Apply the above ContainerStyle to your listview. It should work.

**NOTE**: Step 1 is necessary, because ContainerStyle is no longer honored on Windows 8.1 when ItemsPanel is an ItemsStackPanel(which is the default).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263110.aspx

Comment: It does sort of work, but as described in the question: "Neither can I set visibility on the TextBlock in TemplateHeader 'cause that will leave a small space and not be completely invisible."

Comment: small space? Since your group header just contains a textblock, if you hide it, the entire header will be hidden, there should no more space left.

Comment: But there is :-/ And I can't find anyway to remove it.

Comment: That's weird. I have tested the code, and didn't see any space left.(Windows 8.1). Maybe you can post a screen capture.

Comment: Yes, here is one https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10000243/gap-in-top.png . As you can see there's a small margin in the top. I cannot remove with any method I can think of.

Comment: If I manually set  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter> in the HeaderContainerStyle it dissapears as expected. But I of course need it to be depending on the header title.

Comment: I have edited my answer. It turns out the small space is the margin of the ContentControl in the default group header ControlTemplate. You can just remove it directly.

Comment: Wow great. I have just returned home now, and haven't got the running code here. I'll be sure to test this out first thing in the morning. Thank you for this! :)

Comment: It would still be very very nice to find out why I cannot bind in the HeaderContainerStyle, though :)

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why binding in the HeaderContainerStyle would not work either.Maybe you can traverse the visual tree and find the position of ListViewHeaderItem. btw: there is another way to hide the group header - Just set the HidesIfEmpty property of GroupStyle to true. Then hide all the items of a group whoes header you want to hide.Good luck

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I still want to show the items though. Like some of them are in a group and some of them aren't. What does the position of the ListViewHeaderItem in the visual tree give me? Forgive me if that should be obvious, I'm still pretty new to XAML.

Comment: I've updated the question with new findings. I'll still try out your solution tomorrow :)

Comment: I have tried to traverse the visual tree of ListViewItem upward, but can not find any elment of type ListViewHeaderItem. If we can get the instance of ListViewHeaderItem, then we can set the binding in code behind directly.

Comment: Ok. We ended up doing this:                         <GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-8,0,0" />
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>. That is another pragmatic way to "undo" the margin. We chose this over "changing the panel" solution, 'cause we were not sure what sideeffects the panel changing would have. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to the `Visibility` property which is of type [`Visibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visibility). My guess is that the `GroupHasHeader` property is a boolean; you should use a [Boolean to visibility converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988532/boolean-to-visibility-converter-in-win-rt-xaml-not-working-first-time).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The GroupHasHeader is returning Visibility though. So that unfortunately not it. I'll update the answer to make the name more clear.

Comment: Can you see the binding error in the Output window when debugging your application?

Comment: There's no binding errors in the output no :(
It is as if there is no data context available at all.

Comment: If I for example use a converter for the binding (I have tried a lot of things) the converter will not be called.

Comment: I've updated the question with links to the docs which actually explains why. Unfortunately not how to get around it.